# How to get service executable file path

Tags: .net, windows-services

Is there anyways to get the executable file path of a running Windows service without requiring administrator execution level privilege in .Net? (Without causing the UAC to get the user's confirmation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's a possible solution using WMI:

```
using System.Management;


String query = String.Format("SELECT PathName FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '{0}'", serviceName);

using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query)) {
    foreach(ManagementObject mo in mos.Get()) 
        Console.WriteLine(mo["PathName"].ToString());
}
```

Make sure to wrap the `ManagementObjectSearcher` in a `using` block because it is a resource and needs to be disposed of properly.

I am not sure if this requires elevated permissions to run, but it does require WMI to be installed and running on the machine.  To check if WMI is running, open the services snap-in and look for Windows Management Instrumentation.  You can also enable it by running `net start winmgmt` from the command line.

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid query" exception on mos.Get()

Comment: @LostInLib My apologies... I had forgotten to enclose the service name in single quotes.  I updated my answer to reflect this change. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try getting from Registry:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
.
.
.

RegistryKey hklm = Registry.LocalMachine;
hklm = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SERVICE_NAME");

string servicePath = hklm.GetValue("ImagePath");
```

Comment: Reading form registry requires administrator execution level privileged. Doesn't it?

Comment: While this isn't the ideal way to get this information, I have fallen back on it similar to above but with a few edits I have just made.  Needs testing to know on the UAC prompt, but nearly any user can query this portion of the registry unhindered I believe.