# Path to the executable of a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How can I get the path to the executable of a specific windows service from another program ?
Unfortunately the class ServiceController (System.ServiceProcess) doesn't provide a method or property for that !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get service executable file path.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045065/how-to-get-service-executable-file-path)

Comment: @marc_s: I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate, the other one seems to ask specifically for a non admin way of doing it, which isn't mentioned in this one.

Answer (score 18):

There's always the WMI class `Win32_Service` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), specifically the `PathName`.

This works:

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Service");
foreach(ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
{
    if(mo.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString() == "<Short name of your service>")
    {
        return mo.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString().Trim('"');
    }
}
```

Comment: The PathName seems like the actual commandline for the service, i.e. it includes the parameters along with the executable filepath.

Comment: And do not forger to add `System.Management` in your project reference. Source : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1798212/1529139

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain them from here using the Registry in HKLM:

```
 System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Service
```

Look for the ImagePath value.