# Programmatically check if a windows service is running c#

Tags: c#

I am writing an app to check to see if certain software is installed. One of my cases im looking for a service. I know the full path of the service. i.e. "c:\some folder\MyService.exe" I want to check to see if the service is installed and running. I have tried process.GetProcessbyName, but running into issues with 64 bit vs 32 bit processes. I've also tried ManagementObject but i keep getting invalid object path. Is it possible to get a service knowing only the path to the executable?

I know only the name and path of the executable. There may be more than one version of the executable as well, each with a different service name, which i do not have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178147/how-can-i-verify-if-a-windows-service-is-running

Comment: If you you know the name of the service you could use `sc query <name>` and check whether the exit code is zero.

Comment: I know the name of the executable, not the service name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into the ServiceController / Management object for the executable path. Then based the executable path determine whether the service is running.

How to get executable path : [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728578/how-to-get-phyiscal-path-of-windows-service-using-net) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071215/path-to-the-executable-of-a-windows-service) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828588/finding-the-actual-executable-and-path-associated-to-a-windows-service-using-c-s)

Borrowed from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071304/2788979) above

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Service");
foreach(ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
{
    if(mo.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString().Trim('"') == "<your executable path>")
    {
        return mo.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString(); // or return true;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, and a comment suggested `PathName` may return command line arguments as well, so you may need to write another method to separate the path from the arguments (I'm assuming it'll just be a split on the string), and pass `PathName` to it in `If` statement..

Comment: Great this worked to check if it is installed, now i just need to check the state to see if its running. Thanks.

Comment: I used if (mo.GetPropertyValue("PathName").ToString().Trim('"').StartsWith(fileInfo.FullName)) to ignore the command line params

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can check if the service is installed or not , also get the status of the service

```
public static string CheckService(string ServiceName)
        {
            //check service
            var services = ServiceController.GetServices();
            string serviceStatu = string.Empty;
            bool isServiceExist = false;
            foreach (var s in services)
            {
                if (s.ServiceName == ServiceName)
                {
                    serviceStatu = "Service installed , current status: " + s.Status;
                    isServiceExist = true;
                }


            }

            if (!isServiceExist)
            {
                serviceStatu= "Service is not installed";
            }

            return serviceStatu;
        }
```

`Console.WriteLine(CheckService("Service name"));`

you need to add `System.ServiceProcess` to the project reference